# ExtJs default alignement is right

Tags: css, extjs

I am creating a sample in Extjs and face a issue by default all the element are align from right.
My code for this

```
 Ext.define('DemoApp.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    plugins: 'viewport',
    fullscreen: true,
    requires: [
        'DemoApp.view.main.MainController',
        'DemoApp.view.main.MainModel',
        'Ext.menu.',
        'Ext.rtl.'
    ],
    rtl: true,
    xtype: 'app-main',

    controller: 'main',
    items:[{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items:[{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Home',
            margin: '0,0,0,0',
            height: '80'
        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Resellers',
            margin: '0,0,0,0',
            height: '80'
        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Organizations',
            margin: '0,0,0,0',
        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Groups',
            margin: '0,0,0,0'
        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Users',
            margin: '0,0,0,0'
        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Surveys',
            margin: '0,0,0,0'
        },{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Alerts',
            margin: '0,0,0,0'
        },{

            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Settings',
            margin: '0,0,0,0'
        }]
    }]
});
```

same problem in all of my view.
In login view error messages is showing in right corner where as textfield is in left corner.
I am unable to find out the cause by it is?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could post a working fiddle with you code running.

Comment: isn't that what the rtl (right to left) feature is supposed to do?

Comment: Yes @Scriptable you're right, if the OP could maybe omit or change `rtl` to false it should be fine.